# Find the limit $ \lim_{x \to (\frac{1}{2})^{-}} \frac{\ln(1 - 2x)}{\tan \pi x} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital, substitution

## Question

$$
  \lim_{x \to (\frac{1}{2})^{-}} \frac{\ln(1 - 2x)}{\tan \pi x} 
$$

I'm not sure how to go about this limit, I've tried to apply L'Hopital's rule
(as shown).

It seems that the form is going to be forever indeterminate? Unless I'm missing
something, but the limit is (apparently) zero.

## Working

As this is in the indeterminate form of $- \infty / + \infty$, apply L'Hopital's rule.

Let $\frac{\ln(1 - 2x)}{\tan \pi x} = f/g$, then

$f' = \frac{-2}{1 - 2x}$ , and  $f'' = \frac{-4}{(1 - 2x)^2}$

$g' = \pi \sec^2 \pi x$ (which is equal to $\pi (\tan^2 (\pi x )+ 1)$ ) and

$g'' = 2 \pi^2 \sec^2 (\pi x) \tan \pi x $ ( or
$2 \pi^2 (\tan^2 (\pi x) + 1) \tan \pi x$
)

Using the first derivatives gives

$$
  \lim_{x \to (\frac{1}{2})^{-}}
  \frac{\frac{-2}{1 - 2x}}{\pi \sec^2 \pi x}
$$

Which is in the form

$$
  \frac{- \infty}{+ \infty}
$$

So that I would now use the second derivative, which is

$$
  \lim_{x \to (\frac{1}{2})^{-}}
  \frac{
    \frac{-4}{(1 - 2x)^2}
  }{
    2 \pi^2 \sec^2 (\pi x) \tan \pi x
  }
$$

Or

$$
  \lim_{x \to (\frac{1}{2})^{-}}
  \frac{
    \frac{-4}{(1 - 2x)^2}
  }{
    2 \pi^2 (\tan^2 (\pi x) + 1) \tan \pi x
  }
$$

But this is still in an indeterminate form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were doing fine:

> Using the first derivatives gives
>   $$  \lim_{x \to (\frac{1}{2})^{-}}
>   \frac{\frac{-2}{1 - 2x}}{\pi \sec^2 \pi x}$$

Now simplify a bit first:
$$\frac{\frac{-2}{1 - 2x}}{\pi \sec^2 \pi x} = \frac{2\cos^2\pi x}{\pi \left(2x-1\right)}$$
Applying l'Hôpital to the fraction in this form gives the easy $-\sin\left( 2\pi x\right)$, which evaluates to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this was easiest for me to follow, and probably what the
text may expected.

Some notes to consider adding, maybe they're useful to others learning.

($*$) As $D_x \left( 2 \cos^2 \pi x \right) = -4 \cos(\pi x) \sin (\pi x)$ ,
using trig identity $2\sin(a)\cos(a) = sin(2a)$ gives $-4 \cos(\pi x) \sin (\pi
x) = - 2 \sin (2 \pi x)$.

Then $D_x(\pi (2x - 1)) = 2 \pi$.

We then have 

$$  \frac{- 2 \sin (2 \pi x)}{2 \pi }= \frac{ - \sin (2 \pi x) }{ \pi}$$ And as $x \to 1/2$ (from $x < 1/2$ ) then $\sin(2 \pi x) \to 0$, which gives
the result $\frac{0}{\pi} = 0$.

Comment: @baxx You're welcome! Don't forget the extra factor $\pi$ from the chain rule, which is why it even simplifies to $-\sin 2\pi x$.

Comment: ah yes `>.<`, I was write by "luck" rather than method there, as the denominator doesn't affect the value as it's constant (and the numerator $\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, the result happens to stay the same here but your teacher might not like forgetting about the chain rule ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x-\frac{1}{2}=y$. Hence, $x=\frac{1}{2}+y$ and
 $$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^{-}} \frac{\ln(1 - 2x)}{\tan \pi x} =-\lim_{y\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\ln(-y)}{\cot{\pi y}}=\pi\lim_{y\rightarrow0^-}\left(-y\ln(-y)\right)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

As $x<\dfrac12\iff2x-1<0$

set $1-2x=y$

$$F=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln y}{\tan\dfrac{\pi(1-y)}2}=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln y}{\cot\dfrac{\pi y}2}$$

Applying L'Hospital's $$F=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\sin^2\dfrac{\pi y}2}{-\dfrac\pi2\cdot y}\cdots=0$$  using $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$

Answer (score 2):

You do not need de l'Hospital rule for the evaluation of such limit:
$$\lim_{x\to(1/2)^{-}}\frac{\log(1-2x)}{\tan(\pi x)}=\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{\log(2z)}{\cot(\pi z)}=\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{z\log(2z)}{z\cot(\pi z)} =\frac{0}{\frac{1}{\pi}}=0.$$
It is enough to exploit a substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{2}-z$ and the well-known limits (that should be studied *before* approaching de l'Hospital rule, the Stolz-Cesàro theorem and so on)
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1,\qquad \forall\epsilon>0,\;\;\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{\varepsilon}\log(x)=0.$$

Comment: It seems that more things need to be known in this approach, but it's nice to see one without the rule.

Comment: @baxx: it is just a substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{2}-z$ and two well-known limits...

Comment: I'm not familiar with them, others might not be either.

Comment: I wonder what teachers teach these days. De l'Hopital's rule *before* proving $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1, \qquad \lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{\varepsilon}\log(x) = 0$$ ? Sounds strange to me.

Comment: I think that the identities used should be mentioned in an answer , you're welcome to lament about the education system though if you like

Comment: So one should include the basics of Calculus in every answer about limits? I do not think so. If someone is studying de l'Hospital rule and similar theorems (like Stolz-Cesàro), he/she should be well aware of basic limits. If that is not the case, it is not my fault.

Comment: If the basics of calculus involve stating the identities you're using then obviously my answer is yes, as that's exactly what I just said "I think the identities used should be mentioned in an answer".

Comment: @baxx: fine, answer updated.

Comment: first i've seen - second i've never seen. Seems that it would be easier for people to learn from the post now - cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} - x$. As $x \to \displaystyle \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{-}$, $y \to 0^{+}$. Then:

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to \Big( \frac{1}{2} \Big)^{-}} \frac{\ln(1-2x)}{\tan(\pi x)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln(2y)}{\tan\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi y \Big)} $$

Because $\displaystyle \tan\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi y \Big) = \frac{1}{\tan(\pi y)}$, we have:

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln(2y)}{\tan\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi y \Big)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0^{+}} \ln(2y) \tan(\pi  y). $$

As $y \to 0$, $\tan(\pi y) \sim \pi y$. Therefore:

$$ \ln(2y) \tan(\pi y) \mathop{\sim} \limits_{y \to 0^{+}} \pi y \ln(2y). $$

As a consequence :

> $$ \lim \limits_{x \to \Big( \frac{1}{2} \Big)^{-}} \frac{\ln(1-2x)}{\tan(\pi x)} = 0. $$